# Excel: How can I create a slicer based on data from multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, powerpivot

I'm using PowerQuery and Power Pivot to analyze some data. I would like to create a slicer based on data from multiple columns. Typically slicers are tied to a single column.

The below table is a simple example I contrived to illustrate what I'm trying to do. I'd like to create a slicer, natively in Excel or using VBA, that allows me to slice this data by borough (Brooklyn, Manhattan, etc.). This would be straightforward if every employee worked in one and only one location, but some employees (Smith and Jessop) work in multiple.

| Employee | Brooklyn | Manhattan | Bronx | Staten Island | Queens |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary Shields |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| Brian Jones |  |  |  | 1 |  |
| John Smith | 1 |  | 1 |  |  |
| Martin Casey |  | 1 |  |  |  |
| Evelyn Jessop |  |  | 1 | 1 |  |

I *could*, but *really* don't want to, have multiple rows per employee, each tied to a single borough, but this is an ugly solution and undesirable in my real analysis which is much more complex than the above. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I should add that my analysis already utilizes a number of slicers so, while the above could probably be accomplished with filters or some other mechanism, I'd rather keep it consistent with what I have for the benefit of the consumers of said analysis.

Comment: The easiest is,, if possible TRANSFORM the data in the TABLE , as soon City Name's will be in One Column your job will done or another is VBA macro!!

Comment: @RajeshS Thanks for your response. if the borough name is in one column then entries would presumably need to be delimited (using a comma or otherwise) for those with multiple boroughs. Otherwise it leads back to needing multiple rows per employee. A VBA macro might be the way to go, but do you have any examples of VBA macros that allow one to filter a pivot table using a slicer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to filter as you want, you need to multiply rows, the good news is that you can do it in power query, here is the code for that:

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Employee"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{{"Attribute", "location"}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Renamed Columns", {"Employee"}, #"Renamed Columns", {"Employee"}, "Renamed Columns", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Renamed Columns" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Renamed Columns", {"location"}, {"EmployeeLocations"})
in
    #"Expanded Renamed Columns"
```

few example screenshots:

[image]

[image]

## Update for counting entries:

To calculate totals, you need to load your data by selecting "add to data model" option

[image]

Now you can calculate "distinct count" of employees, which will do what you need.

[image]

Or you can do the same for locations too for calculating row totals, unfortunately there is no way to calculate correctly both totals at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @Máté Juhász. I accepted the answer because it does exactly what I asked. The only issue is that grand totals will always be 1 (since we're averaging values). Do you happen to know any way of summing the grand totals (even if the column values are averages)?

Comment: Do you need a real sum (expect numbers other than 1)or just the count of entries?

Comment: For example, taking your second screenshot the column grand totals would look as follows: Bronx would be 2, Brooklyn 1, Staten Island 1. (I greatly appreciate your help!)

Comment: @user27654 please see my update

Comment: That is _amazing_. Thank you so much. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me. Thanks so much!